# Applet component is not visible if used in different layouts

Tags: java, swing, applet

I'm developing *applet* for electronic sign and I needed to make some changes about components. I have a button called `geriButton`and it is used in `jPanel2` and `jPanel10`.

It is shown in `jPanel10` but not in `jPanel2`.I need `geriButton` on my `jPanel2` too. I tried to find answer but no luck. I provided the code below.Thanks!

EDIT: I made another component called `geriButton2` and gave the same functionality and it worked.
However, I want to use same component `geriButton` in both `jPanel2` and `jPanel10` .  Hope someone can figure it out.

EDIT2:[image]

`jPanel2` and `jPanel10` should like this. I mean, I need the same component( `geriButton` ) placed in both `jPanel2` and `jPanel10`

```
javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
                jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
                jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(jPanel2Layout
                        .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout
                                .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(jPanel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(okudumCheckLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGap(190)
                                        .addComponent(okudumCheckBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))

                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING,
                                        jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(geriButton)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jImzalaB)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(indirButton))).addContainerGap()
                                ));

                jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(jPanel2Layout
                        .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap()
                                .addComponent(jPanel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 250, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                        .addComponent(okudumCheckLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(okudumCheckBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED).addContainerGap()
                                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout
                                        .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                        .addComponent(geriButton)
                                        .addComponent(jImzalaB)
                                        .addComponent(indirButton)).addContainerGap()
                                ));
                jPanel10.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
                javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel10Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel10);
                jPanel10.setLayout(jPanel10Layout);
                jPanel10Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                        jPanel10Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(jPanel10Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75,
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50,
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(geriButton)));
                jPanel10Layout.setVerticalGroup(jPanel10Layout
                        .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel10Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel4).addGap(50)
                                .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(geriButton)));
```

Comment: Post [mcve] & image of how it should look.

Comment: @AndrewThompson added image.

Comment: Where is the MCVE?

Comment: @AndrewThompson when I'll have time(probably after 7 pm), I'll add MCVE. I'm not available right now sorry about that.